# Displaying contacts from contact list program in java

Tags: java

I am new to programming and object oriented design. This is my last requirement to finish my bachelors degree (not in programming). I am a bit confused with how to make object oriented work, and nothing I look at seems to help. The assignment is to create a contact list that uses inheritance, polymorphism,and collections. I need a contact list that stores two types of contacts: business and personal. I need prompt 1 to add a contact and then ask 1 for personal or 2 for business.  Prompt 2 will allow user to display the output of a chosen contact and prompt 3 will quit.

I have the following class and subclasses built. I am pretty sure the classes are built right but after adding either type of contact, when I choose 2 in order to view I can only see the info from the super class and not the subclass (ie: Job Title & Organization or Date of Birth). Any help would be awesome, I just need to get through this, then I will gladly leave programming to those that know what they are doing.

I apologize for the long post but thought I should show everything.

Here is my main class:

```
package contactlist;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactList {

/*ArrayList<List.Contact> contactlist;*/

List<Contact> contactlist = new ArrayList<>();


/* Contact contact; */
private int top = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    /* Contact contact;
    contact = new Contact();
    List.Contact c;
    c = contact; */
    ContactList list = new ContactList();

    BufferedReader keyIn;
    keyIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String choose = "";
    while (true) {

        System.out.println("\n[1] Add contact");
        System.out.println("[2] View all contacts");
        System.out.println("[3] Quit");
        System.out.print("Choose : ");

        try {
            choose = keyIn.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        switch (choose) {
            case "1":
                list.addContact();
                break;
            case "2":
                list.viewContacts();
                break;
            case "3":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error");
                break;
         }

       }
    }

public ContactList() {
    this.contactlist = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addContact() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader keyIn;
    keyIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String address;
    String email;
    String phone;
    String jobTitle;
    String organization;
    String dateOfBirth;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter Specify the contact type (1) Personal
    or (2) Business: ");
    int contactType = input.nextInt();
    if (contactType == 1) {
        System.out.print("First Name: ");
        firstName = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        lastName = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        address = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("E-mail address: ");
        email = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Phone number: ");
        phone = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
        dateOfBirth = keyIn.readLine();

        PersonalContact entry;
        entry = new PersonalContact(firstName, lastName, address, email, 
        phone, dateOfBirth);
        contactlist.add(entry);
        top++;
        try {
            entry.write();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    } else if (contactType == 2) {
        System.out.print("First Name: ");
        firstName = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        lastName = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        address = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("E-mail address: ");
        email = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Phone number: ");
        phone = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Job Title: ");
        jobTitle = keyIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Organization: ");
        organization = keyIn.readLine();

        BusinessContact entry;
        entry = new BusinessContact(firstName, lastName, address, email, 
        phone, jobTitle, organization);
        contactlist.add(entry);
        top++;
        try {
            entry.write();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

}

public void viewContacts() {
for (int index = 0; index < top; index++) {
    System.out.println((index + 1) + " First Name " +
    contactlist.get(index).getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name " + contactlist.get(index).getLastName());
    System.out.println("Address: " + contactlist.get(index).getAddress());
    System.out.println("E-mail: " + contactlist.get(index).getEmail());
    System.out.println("Phone: " + contactlist.get(index).getPhone());
    System.out.println("Job Title " + contactlist.get(index).getJobTitle());
    System.out.println("Organization " +  contactlist.get(index).
    getOrganization());
    System.out.println("Date of Birth " + contactlist.get(index).
    getDateOfBirth());
    }
    }
}
```

Contact Class:

```
package contactlist;

public class Contact {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String email, String phone){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getfirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String setfirstName(){
        return (this.firstName = firstName);
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public String setlastName(){
        return (this.lastName = lastName);
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public String setAddress(){
        return (this.address = address);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public String setEmail(){
        return (this.email = email);
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public String setPhone(){
        return (this.phone = phone);
    }

    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    String getJobTitle() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    String getOrganization() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    String getDateOfBirth() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Business Contact Subclass:

```
package contactlist;

public class BusinessContact extends Contact {

    private String jobTitle;
    private String organization;

    public BusinessContact(String firstName, String lastName, String address, 
    String email, String phone, String jobTitle, String organization) {
        super(firstName, lastName, address, email, phone);
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(String organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    void write() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates. 
    }

}
```

Personal Contact Subclass:

```
package contactlist;

public class PersonalContact extends Contact {

    private String dateOfBirth;

    public PersonalContact(String firstName, String lastName, String address, 
        String email, String phone, String dateOfBirth) {
        super(firstName, lastName, address, email, phone);
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    void write() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: You should implement the `toString()` method in both of your subclasses, and use contact.toString() to view a contact. This will call the overriden method

Comment: Within your `viewContacts` method - why not use the size of `contactlist` in the for loop. E.g : `for (int index = 0; index < contactList.size(); index++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not have getters for Organization,job title and dob in the base class since these are the properties of the individual derived classes. What you should do is override the viewContacts methods and first call the super.override and then display the derived class members

```
    package contactlist;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ContactList {

    /*ArrayList<List.Contact> contactlist;*/

    List<Contact> contactlist = new ArrayList<>();


    /* Contact contact; */
    private int top = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /* Contact contact;
        contact = new Contact();
        List.Contact c;
        c = contact; */
        ContactList list = new ContactList();

        BufferedReader keyIn;
        keyIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String choose = "";
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("\n[1] Add contact");
            System.out.println("[2] View all contacts");
            System.out.println("[3] Quit");
            System.out.print("Choose : ");

            try {
                choose = keyIn.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            switch (choose) {
                case "1":
                    list.addContact();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    list.viewContacts();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    break;
             }

           }
        }

    public ContactList() {
        this.contactlist = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addContact() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader keyIn;
        keyIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String address;
        String email;
        String phone;
        String jobTitle;
        String organization;
        String dateOfBirth;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter Specify the contact type (1) Personal
        or (2) Business: ");
        int contactType = input.nextInt();
        if (contactType == 1) {
            System.out.print("First Name: ");
            firstName = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Last Name: ");
            lastName = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Address: ");
            address = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("E-mail address: ");
            email = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Phone number: ");
            phone = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
            dateOfBirth = keyIn.readLine();

            PersonalContact entry;
            entry = new PersonalContact(firstName, lastName, address, email, 
            phone, dateOfBirth);
            contactlist.add(entry);
            top++;
            try {
                entry.write();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        } else if (contactType == 2) {
            System.out.print("First Name: ");
            firstName = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Last Name: ");
            lastName = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Address: ");
            address = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("E-mail address: ");
            email = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Phone number: ");
            phone = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Job Title: ");
            jobTitle = keyIn.readLine();
            System.out.print("Organization: ");
            organization = keyIn.readLine();

            BusinessContact entry;
            entry = new BusinessContact(firstName, lastName, address, email, 
            phone, jobTitle, organization);
            contactlist.add(entry);
            top++;
            try {
                entry.write();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }

    }

    public void view() {
    for (int index = 0; index < top; index++) {
        contactlist.get(index).viewContact();
        }
        }
    }
```

CONTACT CLASS:

```
package contactlist;

    public class Contact {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String 
    email, String phone){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getfirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String setfirstName(){
        return (this.firstName = firstName);
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public String setlastName(){
        return (this.lastName = lastName);
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public String setAddress(){
        return (this.address = address);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public String setEmail(){
        return (this.email = email);
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public String setPhone(){
        return (this.phone = phone);
    }

    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

public void viewContacts() {
System.out.println(this.getfirstName());
System.out.println(this.getlastName());
.....
}
```

Business Contact Subclass:

```
package contactlist;

    public class BusinessContact extends Contact {

    private String jobTitle;
    private String organization;

    public BusinessContact(String firstName, String lastName, String address, 
    String email, String phone, String jobTitle, String organization) {
        super(firstName, lastName, address, email, phone);
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(String organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    void write() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To 
    change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates. 
    }

public void viewContacts() {
super.viewContacts();
System.out.println(this.getOrganization());
System.out.println(this.getJobTitle());
}
    }
```

Similarly you can do for the other class do. I was just giving an idea.

Comment: "and then append the derived class memebers" - what?

Comment: I meant if you are using a string builder or something to display the member values.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping this newbie out.  Vwin I went with your suggestion and I have it working now.  Thanks!!

Comment: Sure. Glad I can help. But do understand the logic behnd this

Comment: So I was wrong, I thought I had it and understood it but I am still getting the following when I run my program:                                            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.                                                                                   at contactlist.ContactList.viewContacts(ContactList.java:141)
at contactlist.ContactList.main(ContactList.java:48)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Contact> contactlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

It looks like your contactList is in fact the superclass object of type `Contact`, and with that said you will not be able to access the methods/attributes of the subclass because it doesn't know about them, and I imagine you have tried but it will tell you symbol not found I believe.

Maybe you could make another class that actually contains two collections, one for `PersonalContact` and `BusinessContact`, and add a method that will add this to the appropriate list. It might be overkill, but it is the only thing I can think of for this, and you would be satisfying your `Collection` requirement still. Hope it helps, and gives you a place to start.